# In the Dutch salary system, how do the "steps" ("trede") work?

Tags: salary, netherlands

The salary system in Dutch academia is based on a number of "scales" (schaal), which are related to the different academic ranks. The salary in the same scale can vary considerably, depending on the "step" (trede) on which the employee is positioned  (see the current [salary table](https://www.utwente.nl/nl/hr/arbeidsvoorwaarden/salaris_beloning/salarisschalen/salarisschalen-1-feb-2019.pdf)). In job offerings, the scale is usually specified in the job advertisement, whereas the step depends on the candidate and can be subject to negotiation.

1. How does one rise in "steps"? Is it bound to certain achievements, or does it happen automatically after a certain time (what are the time intervals in this case)?
2. How is the starting step for a new employee usually determined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You automatically go up one step per year, until you reach the top of the scale. Starting points are determined by HR, based on an estimate of how many 'years' into the scale you already should be. For example, a postdoc would typically begin on (I think) 10-4, to account for the time spent doing the PhD (note that the Promovendus - PhD student - scale P matches the start of scale 10).

I imagine that it is theoretically possible to refuse someone an increment, or advance them by several steps at once - but I've never heard of it actually happening.

Once you hit the top of a scale, you're stuck there until you can get promoted to the next scale (which requires an explicit process to be followed).

(The other quirk of the Dutch system is that your annual salary is typically 14x the number in this table: 12 monthly payments, plus a vacation payment and an annual bonus.)

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up question, since you mention that the starting step is determined by HR, I wonder if it can still be negotiated (for example, when starting as an assistant professor that brings in job-relevant experiences from a previous post-doc).

Comment: Good answer in general, just a couple of points: it is actually quite regular a jump in scale or several jumps in steps without _explicit_ achievements (I have seen people promoted to scale 14 without ever had funding). It does not always depends on experience. A UD2 with 15 year postdoc and a UD2 with 2 year postdoc will both get 11-0 salary scale (I have actually witnessed it).

Comment: @PsySp Is there an explanation how the jumps in the steps/scales came to be? Do you know if the UD2's in this case tried to negotiate?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper There is not always an explanation (at least to me: im not a manager, just a UD). I doubt that negotiation would give you something more than a single step (from 11-0 to 11-1) but it depends on the academic unit. In short, I think (at least in my unit) there is much in-discrepancy between salary scales of people of similar experience and I am really not sure what is the rationale behind this, since there is no obvious reason. Another point that might play role is the 30% ruling, Do you have it?

Comment: @PsySp Interesting, it surprises me a bit that there is so much discrepancy and no clear rationale. Sounds like it wouldn't be a completely far-fetched idea to negotiate. I would have 30% ruling, so that's nice either way.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper If you have the 30%, then your negotiation power will drop significantly, as you might imagine, if there was any to start with (depends the unit). Also, given the recent developments on 30% ruling, I wouldn't really count too much that you will actually get the full duration (I think 5 years). Also, a peripheral university might be more slack in negotiations

Comment: @PsySp Regarding the 30% ruling, I noticed they recently shortened the duration from eight to five years. Are there any indications that they will shorten it again?

Comment: @PsySp (Oddly, any sign of instability of the 30% ruling at least produces support for my case in starting-trede negotiations ;))

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Well, it is not only that they simply shortened the duration from 8 to 5 years, but they did so _retroactively_ (people that they have been promised 8 years end up with 5). I think you might be right: if they use in the negotiations the argument that you would benefit from the 30% you can have the counter-argument that it is not a rule to rely, even if promises from the government have been made. The current government hates the 30% ruling.

Comment: @PsySp "The current government hates the 30% ruling." Is there any web resource like news articles etc. that one could point to as evidence for that?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper On top of my head, not really: this is the general feeling supported by the fact that they backed down from their promise and retroactively reduced the duration and that they based their decision on a completely arbitrary interpretation of the Dialogic report. Simply mentioning that will maybe do the trick (but don't bring it up unless they do)

Comment: @PsySp Thanks, that's valuable advice! I also found the earlier question here about the 30% ruling and noticed that you were directly affected by the retroactive decision. That sucks.